# Azure SQL slow first query

Tags: azure-sql-database

We are experiencing that the first execution of a query against an index is very slow. It's like there is a cold start of the index. The table is big with millions of rows.

1. execution: 30+sec
2. execution: 4ms

**Database script:**

```
CREATE TABLE [Audits] (
    [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Timestamp] datetime2 NOT NULL,
    [PackageUid] nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
    [DeviceUid] nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Audits] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
);

CREATE INDEX [IX_Audits_DeviceUid] ON [Audits] ([DeviceUid]);
CREATE INDEX [IX_Audits_PackageUid] ON [Audits] ([PackageUid]);
CREATE INDEX [IX_Audits_Timestamp] ON [Audits] ([Timestamp]);
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [Audits] AS [f]
WHERE [f].[DeviceUid] = "04B6481955104083"
ORDER BY [f].[Timestamp] DESC

SELECT *
FROM [Audits] AS [f]
WHERE [f].[DeviceUid] = "04B6481955104083"
ORDER BY [f].[Timestamp] DESC
OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ONLY
```

Possible causes:

- `nvarchar` is to big for the index to work quickly enough. I could change it down to 50.
- Missing index on DeviceUid and Timestamp

Comment: If you use a serverless vCore-based purchasing model you can configure your sql database with an auto-pause. That means that your database will pause after an certain period time of inactivity. Do you have an auto-pause configured?

Comment: I believe that minimum vCores are set to 2 and writing to the database happens every second

Comment: That sounds like a serverless purchasing model for which auto-pause is available. If you haven't changed the auto-pause setting during creation it is set to 1 hour by default. So if it is inactive for 1 hour it will be paused and wake up once activity recurs. That could possibly slow down your first request if the db has to wake up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> We are experiencing that the first execution of a query against an index is very slow. It's like there is a cold start of the index. The table is big with millions of rows.

SQL Server query plans always read data from the page cache in memory.  If a query needs a page that's not in memory, it enters an PAGEIOLATCH wait while the page is fetched from disk.  Once database pages are in the page cache they stay there until they are aged out by more recently/frequently used page via the [LRU-K](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/170036.170081) page replacement algorithm.

If you have a very large number of rows with `WHERE [f].[DeviceUid] = "04B6481955104083"` then it could take some time for all those pages to be read  from the index for the `count(*)`.  But all those pages might fit in your page cache, so the next run doesn't require any physical IO.

If you look at the actual execution plan, it will have the CPU, IO and Wait stats.

And memory management in serverless Azure SQL Database is a bit different than provisioned VCore or DTU model (or regular SQL Server).

> Memory for serverless databases is reclaimed more frequently than for
> provisioned compute databases. This behavior is important to control
> costs in serverless and can impact performance.

[Serverless Overview - Memory Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/serverless-tier-overview#memory-management)

So you will more often be in a cold-cache scenario in serverless.